# If statement in excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a if statement in a cell that looks for the value in two different cells depending on which one is >0.  Both target cells have a formula that selects a value based upon the value of the cell as determined by the formula.  For example:

Tab_1 has cell K3 that reads it value from Tab_2 either G17 or G56 depending on whether G17 is greather than zero.  The if statement is as follows:

=if(Tab_2!G17>0,Tab_2!G17,Tab_2!G56)

I get no errors with the formula.  If G17 is greater than 0, the formula works fine, but if G17 is not greater than zero, no value is placed in Tab_1!k3.  This is the first time that I have had this problem and do not seem to be able to determine whether it is a syntax issue or if my logic is bad.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to me that the formula is correct.  You can try `Formulas` > `Formula Auditing` > `Evaluate Formula` function to check step-by-step what's wrong with the formula.

Answer (score 0):

I fired up Excel and replicated your scenario. It works fine - when `Tab_2!G17` is zero or less, the value from `Tab_2!G56` correctly appears in Tab_1!K3.

Double check your references - are you sure you have values in the correct cells, and you are referencing the correct worksheets?

Also remember if `Tab_2!G56` contains zero, and you have *deselected* the Excel option `Show a zero in cells that have have zero value` then the cell will appear blank.